# Macro to grab data from various excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro that will grab data from closed excel sheets in a specific folder.

Background: I have a job that is split into sections, but each section is quoted the same way but in a different file. Meaning the cells with the important data are always exactly the same. Ie: C16 is the square footage, C3 is the job cost, etc.

What I want is a blank spreadsheet with one button that will pull the data from each sheet and make a table compiling all the data.

Is it possible to have Excel search the folder where this "blank spreadsheet" is located and pull the data from a sheet Basin 1, then go down one line and do it for the sheet Basin 2, until there are no files left in the folder.

Ie :

Basin 1 xxxx

Basin 2 xxxx

Basin 3 xxxx

Etc.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: as far as i know you must open the work book to have access then wb. Sheets("your sheet name"). cells(2,3). search open and close excel workbook.

Comment: The main issue that I have is each job will have a different basin name. Sometimes its a1, a2, a3 sometimes its g1, g2, g3, etc.

I am able to make excel copy all the content from a workbook in order to export it, but I would need it to be the paths and not the content, so that if there are changes in the future, I don't need to re-export everything. 

the fact that each file will have a different name, I'm not exactly sure how to have it open all the excel sheets in the folder, no matter the name, to copy the content using a path. 

If not i'd do a macro always searching the same ones.

Comment: @KevinFoster the documentation page has enough code samples to get you up and running. Check this link and come back when you run into a brick wall http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1144/loop-through-all-sheets-in-active-workbook#t=201703221549492727315